# how to use async in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I want to make a LINQ  async

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Joins()
{
    var joined = from post in _Posts
                 from commint in _Commints
                 where post.Id == commint.PostId
                 select new
                 {
                     postId = post.Id,
                     commintId = commint.Id,
                     post = post.Body,
                     post.Title,
                     CommintEmail = commint.Email,
                     commint = commint.Body
                 };
    return await joined;   
}
```

all data are returned successfully (when I remove async and await), but my goal is to make the function asynchronous

Comment: ToListAsync should be one of your options

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I tried to type return await joined.toListAsync(). but it is an error.

Comment: return await joined.ToListAsync();

Comment: `_Posts` and `_Commints` - are `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`?

Comment: may be try without var joined

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov they are observable collection, but the join var is  IEnumerable

Comment: It turns out that this is CPU-bound operation. Async has no meaning to CPU-bound code. Async is only relevant for IO-bound code.

Comment: You can take this code to another thread. Use `Task.Run`. Whether it makes sense is up to you. No one knows your context.

Answer (score 0):

if you have just list of items ( no context) you can try this algorithm

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Joins()
{
    return await Task<IEnumerable<object>>.Run(()=> (from post in _Posts
                         from commint in _Commints
                         where post.Id == commint.PostId
                         select new
                         {
                             postId = post.Id,
                             commintId = commint.Id,
                             post = post.Body,
                             post.Title,
                             CommintEmail = commint.Email,
                             commint = commint.Body
                         }).ToList()
            );
}
```

but it doesn't make much sense to me.

If you use net core  EF try this (classical net EF doesnt have async operators, so you can only try to make a custom code using standart algoritm   Task.Run() like above):

```
return await  (from post in  _context.Posts
                 join commint in _context.Commints
              on post.Id equals commint.PostId
                         
                         select new
                         {
                             postId = post.Id,
                             commintId = commint.Id,
                             post = post.Body,
                             post.Title,
                             CommintEmail = commint.Email,
                             commint = commint.Body
                         }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I tried this but not help, in addition, when I type ToListAsync it's not showing it in typing options. I have only toList(), but I typed "using System.Data.Entity;"

Comment: @KhaledJanky What EF version are you using?

Comment: I am using version  6.4.4 of the Entity framework. I found it marked by Microsoft @Serge